# jquery mobile stuck on white screen between transition android

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I'm using:

- jQuery Mobile 1.3.2
- Knockout JavaScript library v2.2.0rc
- Phonegap 2.9.0rc1-0-g002f33d

Lately I'm getting complaints from customer that the app get stuck on white screen between page transition.

The customers are using Galaxy notes4 (android 5.0.1), and Nexus5 (5.1).

I cannot reproduce it on any of my device: S3 (4.3), iphone4, ipad3.

or any of the simulators - I tried Nexus 5 (Google API 22), and Android 5.0.1 API 21.

This only started to happen lately - therefore I assume it's a result of some upgrade in the Android/Browser core.

I'm trying to get hold of the customer device, but until then any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a hold of a customer device, and my first guess was correct:

I disabled slide transition on android

I.e. I comment

```
$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
```